# How to specify optional inputs for nextflow processes?

Tags: nextflow

I'm new to nextflow and have been trying to create a small pipeline for some python scripts I have. However, I have encountered an issue regarding optional inputs to processes that I can't seem to figure out a workaround for. I'm also curious what best practices would be for optional inputs and parameters.

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

params.out = ""
params.kml_1 = null
params.kml_2 = null
params.loc = ""
params.new_data_1 = false
params.new_data_2 = false

process getPolygons {
    input:
    tuple val(db_table), path(path_to_kml), val(new_data)
    val loc
    path path_to_outdir

    def new_data_arg = new_data ? "--new_data" : ""
    def kml_arg = (path_to_kml != null) ? "--kml $path_to_kml" : ""

    script:
    """
    python3 ${baseDir}/bin/polygon_data.py --loc $loc --db_table $db_table $kml_arg $new_data_arg --outdir $path_to_outdir
    """
}

workflow {
    outdir_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.out)
    location_ch = Channel.of(params.loc)

    tables = [
        tuple("Table1", params.kml_1 ? params.new_data_1 : null, params.new_data_1),
        tuple("Table2", params.kml_2 ? params.new_data_2: null, params.new_data_2)
    ]
    tables_ch = Channel.from(tables)

    getPolygons(tables_ch, location_ch, outdir_ch)
}
```

The code worked prior to adding in the optional inputs. This was before I had made `tables` a list of tuples in order to account for the optional parameters in getPolygons: path_to_kml and new_data, instead it was:

`tables = ["Table1", "Table2"]`

I keep running into the error

`ERROR ~ No such variable: new_data` or `ERROR ~ No such variable: path_to_kml`

depending on the order of creating the variables new_data_arg and kml_arg.

Trying the tuple method is the latest thing I have done to address this issue that the program has with the optional parameters new_data and path_to_kml. I previously had them as separate inputs to getPolygons. Could the issue be with creating the variables new_data_arg and kml_arg and using them in the script instead of using new_data and path_to_kml directly? If so, I'm not really sure what the work around is because for my purposes, I need some logic applied to new_data and path_to_kml before adding this information when invoking polygon_data.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this that utilized tuples. First the `ERROR ~ No such variable` issues were due to the variables `new_data_arg` and `kml_arg` not being inside the script component of the process (rookie mistake).

Next, I realized that this would not iterate over the tuples, so I was able to utilize each to do so passing in the tuple as the variable `tuple_info` like so, and used "" instead of null for the path_to_kml as it is a path and there could be issues with null. so this is the final workable version for my process:

```
process getPolygons {
    input:
    each tuple_info
    val loc
    path path_to_outdir

    script:
    def (db_table, path_to_kml, new_data) = tuple_info
    def new_data_arg = new_data ? "--new_data" : ""
    def kml_arg = (path_to_kml != "") ? "--kml $path_to_kml" : ""

    """
    python3 ${baseDir}/bin/polygon_data.py --loc $loc --db_table $db_table $kml_arg $new_data_arg --outdir $path_to_outdir
    """
}
```

I also realize that I could have simplified the `tables` list as theres no reason to build extra logic surrounding params.kml_1 and params.kml_2 when the initialization of the parameters handles this.

```
tables = [
    tuple("Table1", params.kml_1, params.new_data_1),
    tuple("Table2", params.kml_2, params.new_data_2)
]
```

Comment: Optional inputs are much more about channels than elements inside the process block. If you call this process without providing a channel (because it's an optional input), it won't run, so it doesn't matter what you do inside the process block. You must first check outside, and provide an empty channel so that the process is run in the first place. Then, inside it, by checking the input is "empty", you do the magic you want :). We're working on making optional inputs a native feature of Nextflow, just like optional outputs currently are. 